# sql: select rows where group of elements occurs several times in the table

Tags: sql

I am searching for an implementation of the following pseodo-code:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM X
HAVING COUNT(A,B) > 1
```

Here is an example of what the code should do:

Assume table X looks as follows:

```
A   B   C   D
--------------
1   1   0   2
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   0
```

The first and the second row have the same entries in columns A and B, the third column is identical in column B but different in column A. The desired output is columns A,B, and C of rows 1 and 2:

```
1   1   0
1   1   1
```

How could this be implemented? The problem with my pseodo-code is, that COUNT accepts either a single column or all columns (*), but it can't take two out of 4 columns. GROUP BY has the same property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `exists` clause.  This should work in all databases:

```
select a, b, c
from x
where exists (select 1
              from x x2
              where x.a = x2.a and x.b = x2.b and x.c <> x2.c
             );
```

This assumes that the rows have difference `c` values.

This will perform best with an index on `x(a, b)`.

Comment: Very elegant solution, works also without the x.c <> x2.c (I actually don't mind if the entries in column c are the same or not). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one more note on my last comment: of course one needs the x.c <> x2.c (where c is any column) because otherwise also single occurences will be selected (it will find the exact same row in the "exists" test)

Answer (score 0):

For RDMS that supports analytic functions, you can do

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM
(
  SELECT a, b, c, count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY a,b) cnt
  FROM X
)t1
WHERE t1.cnt >1
```

If analytic/windows function are not available , `join` should do the job

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c 
FROM X t1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT a,b
  FROM X 
  GROUP BY a,b
  HAVING COUNT(1) >1
)t2 ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t2.b=t1.b)
```